# True/ False: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$ converges, then $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The solutions in my textbook say this is false, but I do not see how this is any difference from if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ converges, then $a_{k}\rightarrow0$ which is true in the solutions. $f(x)$ may have some discontinuities on some non-natural values of $x$, but shouldn't that not effect the limit's long-term behaviour towards infinity? Am I missing something?

Comment: All you know is that $f \to 0$ along positive integers. It can do whatever it wants between integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ with $f(x) = 0$ for all rational $x$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise.

If you want a continuous example, consider $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all integers $x$, $f(x) = 1$ for all half-integers $x$ and $f(x)$ is linearly interpolated between the nearest integer and half-integer for all other $x$.

Comment: Haven't learned linear interpolation or half integers, but I assume the graph looks like triangles with the top points half-way between integers? i.e. /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ for a continuous example?

Comment: There's nothing to "learn", but yea, you're right

Comment: Yes, saw teeth forever.

Answer (score 2):

For a smooth function, how about
$$f(x) = x\cdot \sin(\pi x)\quad ?$$
For any integer $k$, $f(k) = 0$, but $f$ grows without bound (oscillating positive and negative) as $x$ increases.

And if you think that the positives and negatives "average out" to a limit of 0 (which is incorrect anyway), just take
$$g(x) = x\cdot\sin^2(\pi x)$$
which is always non-negative if $x$ is.

Comment: Fair, but I think either are better than $*$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as phrased is false; consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \ \text{is an integer} \\ 
x & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k) = 0$ since $f(k)$ is zero for each integer $k$, but $f(x)$ does not have a limit towards infinity.

Comment: It would be false even if f were assumed to be continuous.  See my answer.

Comment: True! I'll edit the incorrect implication in my answer, thanks.